# Injective function, continuous at $x$, not locally monotone at $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I set out to prove the following statement or give a counterexample:

> Suppose $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is one to one. Suppose $f$ is
>   continuous at $x\in [a,b]$. Then there is a neighborhood of $x$ on
>   which $f$ is monotone.

I came up with the counterexample 
$$x\mapsto \begin{cases} x & \text{if}\,\, x \in \left[\frac{1}{2^k}, \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\right],\,\,k \,\,\text{an even integer} \\ -x & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

The function is injective, and continuous at zero, but not locally monotone at zero.

Anyone else have some good counterexamples? (Or is mine wrong somehow?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also just do $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x & x\in\mathbb{Q} \\ -x & x\notin\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$

on any closed interval containing $x=0$.

Comment: Ah, much simpler.